# Why pies are flat in geom_scatterpie in R?

Tags: r, pie-chart, scatterpie

Why are the pies flat?

```
    df<- data.frame(
      Day=(1:6),
      Var1=c(172,186,191,201,205,208),
      Var2= c(109,483,64010,161992,801775,2505264), A=c(10,2,3,4.5,16.5,39.6), B=c(10,3,0,1.4,4.8,11.9), C=c(2,5,2,0.1,0.5,1.2), D=c(0,0,0,0,0.1,0.2))

ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(data = df, aes(x = Var1 , y = Var2, group = Var1), cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

[image]

I have tried using `coord_fixed()` and does not work either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the scales of the x- and y-axes.  If you rescaled them to both to have zero mean and unit variance, the plot works.  So, one thing you could do is plot the rescaled values, but transform the labels back into the original scale.  To do this, you would have to do the following:

Make the data:

```
df<- data.frame(
    Day=(1:6),
    Var1=c(172,186,191,201,205,208),
    Var2= c(109,483,64010,161992,801775,2505264), A=c(10,2,3,4.5,16.5,39.6), B=c(10,3,0,1.4,4.8,11.9), C=c(2,5,2,0.1,0.5,1.2), D=c(0,0,0,0,0.1,0.2))
```

Rescale the variables

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(x = c(scale(Var1)), 
           y = c(scale(Var2)))
```

Find the linear map that transforms the rescaled values back into their original values.  Then, you can use the coefficients from the model to make a function that will transform the rescaled values back into the original ones.

```
m1 <- lm(Var1 ~ x, data=df)
m2 <- lm(Var2 ~ y, data=df)
trans_x <- function(x)round(coef(m1)[1] + coef(m1)[2]*x)
trans_y <- function(x)round(coef(m2)[1] + coef(m2)[2]*x)
```

Make the plot, using the transformation functions as the call to labels in the `scale_[xy]_continuous()` functions

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_scatterpie(data=df, aes(x = x, y=y), cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) + 
    scale_x_continuous(labels = trans_x) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = trans_y) + 
    coord_fixed()
```

[image]

There may be an easier way than this, but it wasn't apparent to me.

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful @DaveArmstrong

Answer (score 1):

The range on the y-axis is so large it's compressing the disks to lines.  Change the y-axis to a log scale, and you can see the shapes.  Adding `coord_fixed()` to keep the pies circular:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(data = df, aes(x = Var1 , y = Var2, group = Var1), cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Tech Commodities